# How to use Selenium select class on HTML DOM which has "ul" / "li" tags in it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I assume the developers are using latest HTML version where in the drop down are handled more dynamically and the usage of "ul" and "li" have become more common than the traditional "select".
How do we use Seleniums select class to select by visible text / index on ul / li elements?

The only solution I see: 
1. Click on the drop down.
2. Click the option / text.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class is only capable of working with [HTML `<select>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), it will not be able to deal with custom representations which look like a dropdown but in reality they're just [hyperlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) so you will have to do what real user does, i.e. click at the dropdown followed by the click at the desired option.

The good practice is introducing an abstraction layer via i.e. [Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) design pattern so you would be able to operate code blocks like:

```
myPage.selectFromSomeDropDown("someValue");
```

where `selectFromSomeDropDown` function will contain the relevant implementation.